# JQuery UI - Improper checkbox state icon using .checkboxradio() and .tabs()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've some trouble to properly render a **selected** checkbox when put inside a tabs widget.

Outside the tabs the checkboxes renders correctly.

I prepared a JSFiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/x30gzqo4/8/

```js
$( function() {
  $(".checkbox").checkboxradio();
  $("#guestsData").tabs();
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <label for="test0">This is checked and works</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test0" value="yes" checked="checked" />
</div>
<div id="guestsData">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#guest-0">Tab 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="guest-0">
    <div>
      <label for="test1">This is checked and don't works!</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test1" value="yes" checked="checked" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="test2">This is unchecked</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test2" value="yes" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="guest-1">
    Tab 1 content
  </div>
  <div id="guest-2">
    Tab 2 content
  </div>
  <div id="guest-3">
    Tab 3 content
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or idea is strongly appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved the issue rendering the page normally with all fields empty (and checkboxes unchecked!), then execute an ajax query and filling the form (and checking the checkboxes...) with Javascript:

```
$("#guest").prop("checked", true);
$("#guest").button("refresh");
```

Please don't forget the *refresh*!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like to be some kind of a **JS conflict** between `.tabs()` and `.checkboxradio()`**!!!**

And it is about the `background-position` of the icon located in that nice .png.
[image]

It is used as a `background` and its `background-position` setted to `0% 0%` via JS...
Which correspond to the top-left icon.
And you want the one in the **5th** column, **9th** row.

So the position for this one is `-5 * 16px`  and `-9 * 16px` which is, in clear:

```
"background-position":"-64px -144px"
```

**It took time to nail that!**
It absolutely has to be fixed by JS, since a slight delay is needed to override the glitch.
1ms seems to be enougth to apply the **"bug fix"**.
    *(That really is the right term!)*.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( function() {
    $("#guestsData").tabs();
    $(".checkbox").checkboxradio();
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    var target = $(document).find("#test1").prev().find("span").first();
    
    console.log(target.css("background-position"));
    target.css({"background-position":"-64px -144px"});
    console.log(target.css("background-position"));
  },1);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <label for="test0">This is checked and works</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test0" value="yes" checked />
</div>

<div id="guestsData">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#guest-0">Tab 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="guest-0">
    <div>
      <label for="test1">This is checked and works fine when a <b>BUG FIX</b> is applied!</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test1" value="yes" checked />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="test2">This is unchecked</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test2" value="yes" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="guest-1">
    Tab 1 content
  </div>


  <div id="guest-2">
    Tab 2 content
  </div>


  <div id="guest-3">
    Tab 3 content
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## EDIT!

**I just found a better way to fix that for all checkboxes in tabs.**
   *(And be able to uncheck them!!)*

Only a function that will run on document ready... And two classes are needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( function() {
    $("#guestsData").tabs();
    $(".checkbox").checkboxradio();
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    
    // Fixes the checkbox at checked state on load 
    var target = $(document).find(".ui-tabs .ui-checkboxradio-icon.ui-icon-check")

    // Apply the bugfix.
    target.addClass("bugfix");

    // Handler to "unfix" now...
    target.on("click",function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("unchecked")
    });

  },1);
  
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
}

.bugfix{
  background-position:-64px -144px !important;
}
.bugfix.unchecked{
  background-position:100% 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <label for="test0">This is checked and works</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test0" value="yes" checked />
</div>

<div id="guestsData">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#guest-0">Tab 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="guest-0">
    <div>
      <label for="test1">This is checked and works fine when a <b>BUG FIX</b> is applied!</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test1" value="yes" checked />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="test2">This is unchecked</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test2" value="yes" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="guest-1">
    Tab 1 content
  </div>


  <div id="guest-2">
    Tab 2 content
  </div>


  <div id="guest-3">
    Tab 3 content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you inspect the element, you can see that `background-position` is being overruled by `.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus, .ui-button:hover, .ui-button:focus`.

We need to improve the [Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/css-specificity-and-inheritance/) of `.ui-icon-checked` in CSS to ensure it used.

To correct this, you can do it in CSS:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".checkbox").checkboxradio();
  $("#guestsData").tabs();
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
}

label.ui-checkboxradio-label span.ui-icon-check {
  background-position: -64px -144px;
}

label.ui-checkboxradio-label span.ui-icon-blank {
  background-position: 16px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <label for="test0">This is checked and works</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test0" value="yes" checked="checked" />
</div>
<div id="guestsData">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#guest-0">Tab 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="guest-0">
    <div>
      <label for="test1">This is checked and don't works!</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test1" value="yes" checked="checked" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="test2">This is unchecked</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test2" value="yes" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="guest-1">
    Tab 1 content
  </div>
  <div id="guest-2">
    Tab 2 content
  </div>
  <div id="guest-3">
    Tab 3 content
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: [What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved simply reinforcing two css classes for the background image positioning. For some reason, the positioning of the background image is dislocated in conflict with the Tab css classes.

You can test my JSFiddle with the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ws68uzbj/

```js
$( function() {
    $(".checkbox").checkboxradio();
    $("#guestsData").tabs();
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
}

.ui-icon-blank {
    background-position: 16px 16px !important;
}

.ui-icon-check {
    background-position: -64px -144px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <label for="test0">This is checked and works</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test0" value="yes" checked="checked" />
</div>

<div id="guestsData">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#guest-0">Tab 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guest-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="guest-0">
    <div>
      <label for="test1">This is checked and don't works!</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test1" value="yes" checked="checked" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="test2">This is unchecked</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="test2" value="yes" />
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="guest-1">
    Tab 1 content
  </div>
  
  
  <div id="guest-2">
    Tab 2 content
  </div>
  
    
  <div id="guest-3">
    Tab 3 content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be a race condition between the hover css and regular css states, but overriding them with combo classes did the trick for me.  Anything to make these two background-position, background-color, and border styles to resolve properly.  Sometimes I suspect Firebug is also causing the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same problem with controlgroup. Finally, I add some style and it work with all jquery ui theme

```
.ui-icon-blank {
  background-image: none !important;    
  background-color: #ffffff !important; 
}
.ui-icon-check {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  background-position: -64px -144px !important;
}
```

Comment: You can also use a more complex css rule to take precidence to avoid having to use #important.  While #important works, I save it for when I have some varying mixes from multiple JS open source modules.

Answer (score 0):

May be related to the fact that *radio* checkboxes live within a ".tab" classed element.

Somehow after post POST submission, if these *radio* checkboxes had been checked  prior to submission, the 'ui-state-hover' CSS class gets applied to the first span in the label but only removing it will make the checkmark properly render instead of a caret like `^` symbol from upper-left of the jquery theme *.png* image.

Selector is the label's *id* attribute (label related to the *radio* checkbox input element).

```
$("#other-btn").find("span").first().removeClass("ui-state-hover");
```